# Facebook app scope id to taggable friends id relation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wish to use the API like below:

1. Invite friends who are not on my app from through taggable friends API by tagging them in some stories
2. Once they sign up, show them the stories they were tagged in.

Now the problem is taggable friends id returns id that can only be used for tagging. So when I save tagged stories for that user against that id and when the user logs in, there is no way to match the stories to that user. Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem? In other words, is there a way to get app scoped id from tagged user id?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get any ID from the tagged token. In addition you should *not* be using taggable friends as a method to invite friends, this will not be approved in Facebook Review.

So, there is no solution to this problem because everything here points in the direction of violating Developer policy.

Comment: Also using taggable_friends to do invites will never be approved by Facebook.

Comment: If taggable friends is not the right choice, what do you guys suggest I use? Anything else that can satisfy my use case?